# Unable to run pycallgraph for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cygwin, pip, pycallgraph

I'm using windows 7 , with python 2.7 and pip 8.0.2

i have installed pyCallGraph for python using pip in cygwin

```
pip install pycallgraph
```

When trying to execute it :

```
$ pycallgraph graphviz -- ../main.py
    C:\python27\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts/pycallgraph': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

That's weird because pycallgraph is present in the Script folder and i'm executing the commanf from the same folder

If i ran the command for the second time :

```
$ pip install pycallgraph
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycallgraph in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

I'm new to python , any help will be appreciated , thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think I'm late to the party...
`pip install graphviz`

pycallgraph makes use of graphviz to visualize graphs. Hence, a prerequisite of pycallgraph is graphviz. I had a similar issue, and installing graphviz fixed the problem for me.

Comment: While this may answer the question, code only answers are generally regarded as lo-quality. Providing some more description and context on why will improve the quality of this answer. Thanks.